# .ajax() can't alert data sent from server

Tags: php, jquery

I have this HTML structure :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="view/backoffice/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){               
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../controller/ctrl.test.php",
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and `../controller/ctrl.test.php` actually just to output some date and time, so to simplify, it just like this :

```
<?php
echo '2016/04/22 13:00:00'; 
?>
```

my question is, how to get `2016/04/22 13:00:00` as feedback when ajax is finished? I tried to `json_encode('2016/04/22 13:00:00')` but also didn't show up as alert.

I also read this tutorial : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp, it can fetch txt file without problem, but why in my case, I can't get date from PHP file?

what did I missed here? thank you

Comment: please check your console and network tab

Comment: could you open the ajax endpoint in browser "../controller/ctrl.test.php"? Does it respond correctly?

Comment: url correct? can ajax find this file? or giving any error?

Comment: the problem is here `success:function(data){ alert(data); });`, this should be `success:function(data){ alert(data); }`, without `);`

Comment: Debug into the success and check what is the value of data?

Answer (score 1):

@Robert check by using network capturing feature of browser if data is actually coming in the response body  of the response or not and the format of the data in response .

Answer (score 1):

.Check console for syntax error.

Here a working example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {               
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem :

the problem is here `success:function(data){ alert(data); });` this should be `success:function(data){ alert(data); }`, without `);`

Answer (score 0):

your success function should be like this

```
success:function(data){
 alert(data); }
```

not like this

```
success:function(data){
 alert(data); });
```